# Google sheet / javascript not evaluating dates as expected

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api-php-client

I have a PHP script that records a timestamp in a Google Sheet. When I tried to see if this timestamp is between two other timestamps that I have entered manually into the same sheet, I discovered some odd behavior. I thought it might be because Google added a ' at the start of the string in the cell so I tried doing a substr to remove the apostrophe.

```js
function weirdDate(dateFromPhp) {
  var dateSubStr = new Date(dateFromPhp.substr(1));
  var dateDefault = new Date(dateFromPhp);
  return "dateFromPhp: " + dateFromPhp + " dateSubStr: " + dateSubStr + " dateDefault: " + dateDefault;
}
```

Output is:
dateFromPhp: 16/01/2020 08:33:45 
dateSubStr: Mon Jun 01 2020 08:33:45 GMT+1000 (AEST) 
dateDefault: Thu Apr 01 2021 08:33:45 GMT+1100 (AEDT)

I have no idea why these dates are months or years away from the expected and with different timezones. The operation without the substr resulted in the correct timezone for me.

Any idea how I can make this string into a timestamp with the correct date?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer. I had no idea javascript expected mm/dd/yyyy as the order for the date format.

```js
function weirdDate(dateFromPhp) {
  var dateSubStr = new Date(dateFromPhp.substr(1));
  var dateDefault = new Date(dateFromPhp);
  var dateUs = americanizeDate(dateFromPhp);
    return "dateFromPhp: " + dateFromPhp + " dateSubStr: " + dateSubStr + " dateDefault: " + dateDefault + " dateUS: " + dateUs; 
}

function americanizeDate(ausDate) {
  var dateParts = ausDate.split("/");
  // month is 0-based, that's why we need dataParts[1] - 1
  var usDate = new Date(dateParts[1]+"/"+dateParts[0]+"/"+ dateParts[2]); 
  return usDate;
}
```

Switching the month and the day solved the problem.